# neo4j-uuid causing exceptions in startup of database engine due to class not found

Tags: java, neo4j

Followed install instructions at https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-uuid

Seemed to build successfully

Now running into this error, any thoughts?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/uuid/Generators
    at org.neo4j.extension.uuid.UUIDTransactionEventHandler.<init>(UUIDTransactionEventHandler.java:30)
    at org.neo4j.extension.uuid.UUIDLifeCycle.start(UUIDLifeCycle.java:29)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.uuid.Generators
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the [jar file for the fasterxml.com uuid generator](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.uuid/java-uuid-generator) and copy it to Neo4j's plugins folder.

I'll gonna amend the docs for neo4j-uuid with that one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the general answer is that the class in question cannot be found (yeah, that's what it says, right?) Well, the class can't be found because a dependency is missing. If there is no error at compile time, the class could be found then, so that means that there is a difference between your dependency context at compile time and run time. Possibly you are compiling your code against one version of a library, that includes the class, but you run your compiled code against a different version, which doesn't; or else you have a dependency on a jar that was compiled against some dependency that is not provided together with it. As for the specifics of your case, I don't know, I've never used the Neo4j extension in question, but I would look for whatever jar contains the correct version of `com.fasterxml.uuid.Generators` and make sure its on you classpath.